# Splitting a string into an array ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

I am trying to turn this string

```
"a,bc,c"
```

into this array..

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

I've used split on the comma & iterated through it but I'd like to find a cleaner way.

Thanks!

Comment: `"a,b,c".split(",")` does not solve?

Comment: Please elaborate: why do you not want the 'bc' component of your string to remain as "bc"? Are you keeping only unique single characters? It is unclear what the spec is here.

Comment: What would you like the return value to be if the string were `"a,bc,d"`? What if it were `"aa,aaa,aa"`? Rarely can you make a question clear with a single example. You need to state in words what you want to accomplish. Please do so with an edit, not a comment.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer and voted to close, not because it is vague, which it is, but because you have not responded to either comment asking for a clarification. If you clarify, with an edit, I will retract my actions.

Answer (score 3):

I will use `#scan` and `#uniq` method.

```
"a, bc,c".scan(/[a-z]/).uniq
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here we go, one option:

```
"a, bc,c".gsub(/\W+/, '').chars.uniq

 # Outputs:
 => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Awesome, this really helped!